# Unable to figure out Java/Selenium ChromeDriver download

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

New to automated testing and trying to learn from an outdated Udemy Course. Please help me! I am brand new to this and my google searching is becoming redundant/unhelpful due to my lack of understanding.

Currently on Chrome version 115.0.5790.114 and am using the chromedriver_mac_arm64 for my M1 Macbook Pro (using the last 114 version as another thread suggested on StackOverflow). Everything that I download for 115 and above does not have an exe file for Selenium to recognzie. I tried to Run the Java class with a main and System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/_____/Docs/chromedriver");
and am getting a 'can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.' error.

Update : Fixed. All that was needed was to 'open' the exe file and let it run for a few minutes, and trusting the downloaded file from the internet. I still thank Apple for their enhanced security.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you try to open chromedriver manually. See [here](https://support.apple.com/zh-cn/guide/security/sec5599b66df/web) and [here](https://support.apple.com/zh-cn/HT202491).
2. [Disable Gatekeeper on macOS](https://disable-gatekeeper.github.io/), but I don't know if this works on your Mac version, since I don't know Mac, you can try google [mac disable Gatekeeper](https://www.google.com/search?q=mac%20disable%20Gatekeeper%20&ie=UTF-8).

**NOTE**: *If you try the second option, turn on Gatekeeper after you are done testing!!!*

Hope to help you.

Comment: Did not need to disable Gatekeeper (thankfully). All I had to do was run the exe file for a few minutes and run my program to ensure that it worked. After the first time it is good to go. 
https://thewiredshopper.com/apple-cannot-check-for-malicious-software-error/
Because my chrome is updated to the latest version avail, chromedriver automatically downgraded me to a 114 version for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium `v4.11.0` has been released yesterday(31-Jul23). This version can do the driver management automatically even for chrome browser `v115`, without setting the PATH(`System.setProperty`).

**Solution:** Just upgrade to Selenium `v4.11.0` and use the simple code as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/");

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am using Maven to build, so the latest maven repository that currently exists is still v4.10.0. All I had to do was open the exe file and let the program run for a few minutes. I am embarrassed. https://thewiredshopper.com/apple-cannot-check-for-malicious-software-error/